# Cycle through text file to capture string

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a solution to this issue that I'm having a hard time with: I'm trying to read text from a .txt file with this code.  The line `Monsters[i, j] =  string(col.Split(' '));` is giving me trouble, telling me that string is an invalid expression.  The file is a list of characters and their attributes separated by spaces.  Thanks in advance!

```
String input = File.ReadAllText(@"CharacterAttributes.txt");

int a = 0, b = 0;
string[,] Monsters = new string[24,11];
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    b = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        Monsters[a, b] =  string(col.Split(' '));
        b++;
    }
    b++;
}
```

Comment: Use in the Split the option RemoveEmptyEntries.  You probably have more than one space between columns which create empty entires.

Comment: What is the statement string(...) ? There is no such thing in C#.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng, I'll do that.  I do have tabs between my attributes.

Comment: @chameleon86, that was me trying to overthink things.

Comment: myStr.Split(new char[] {' ','\t'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: @jdweng, thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 3):

From what it appears to me:

- You've already separated each character by row: `var row in input.Split('\n')`
- You've already separated each attribute for the character by space: `var col in row.Trim().Split(' ')`

So, when we get to `Monsters[a,b] = string(col.Split(' '))` (which btw, `string()` is invalid syntax), I see no reason to split any further, and what you're actually trying to do is store the value of `col` to your `Monsters[a,b]`, assuming `a` is each character, and `b` is the attribute for said character.

`Monsters[a,b] = col;` may well be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm very new to this and I tend to over-complicate things.  I did see the invalid syntax, which was the cause of my confusion.  Arrays get me going in loops.  Upvoted.  Most helpful.